# Jquery toggle is effecting all of my share icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide

I am setting up a blog here:
http://www.bluehavenhomes.com/blog

my Jquery:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.Share-button').click(function(){
                $('.share-icon').toggle();    

            });
        });

    </script>
```

This should be pretty simple but my brain is fried. I need for only the share Icon I click on to show the share buttons. right now if you click 1 share icon all buttons for all posts show. I can't id the posts because they auto populate from the blog database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.Share-button').click(function(){
            $(this).closest('.share-icon').toggle();
            //possibly replace .closest() with .siblings() or .next()

        });
    });

</script>
```

By using the *this* selector, you're narrowing to only the element being clicked. From there, you'll need to use either .next(), .siblings(), or.closest() to traverse the DOM and find the element you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, misread that original question.  I've corrected my answer.  Credit should go to @isherwood as they answered it correctly first!

Comment: This is perfect except that it doesn't toggle the share-icon class it targets the share-button class which in turns hides the share-button class. How would I target the share-icon class within "this"?

Comment: Your selector still isn't quite right. It would've been helpful had the OP shown the HTML structure in the question. The button and the related content are siblings. Your example won't return anything.

Comment: Thanks anthony! Siblings worked but closest didn't. I didn't try next.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific in your selectors. This targets only the next sibling of the clicked element:

```
$('.Share-button').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.share-icon').toggle();    
});
```

You could also use a common ancestor element to contain target scope:

```
$('.Share-button').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.share').find('.share-icon').toggle();    
});
```